# Creating IAM role fails with AdministratorAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've got a IAM user with the managed policy `AdministratorAccess` assigned. It's got an access/secret key pair generated and they do work:

```
$ aws-vault exec profile aws sts get-caller-identity                                                            
{
    "UserId": "...",
    "Account": "123...",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123...:user/..."
}
```

However when I want to create a new role using that account, I get:

```
$ aws-vault exec profile aws iam create-role --role-name Test-Role --assume-role-policy-document file://doc.json

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

What could be the reason for the failure?

Answer (score 0):

The session tokens given out by `aws-vault` are not usable for some actions like creating roles. Instead, `aws-vault exec -n profile ...` should be used to use the root profile (not session).